# Conversion string to type long is not valid. When I use combobox to run the program and it does work

Tags: vb.net

When I using combobox to choose table name and it does not working and displaying error message as "Conversion string to type long is not valid". Anyone help me?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click

    lblError1.Text = ""
    lblError2.Text = ""
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim str As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=..\VisitorPass.accdb"
    con = New OleDbConnection(str)
    Dim sql As String = "select AccountName,[Password] from [" & ComboBox1.SelectedItem.trim().ToString() & "] where AccountName='" & txtName.Text.Trim().ToString() & "'and [Password]='" & txtPassword.Text.Trim().ToString() & "'"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
    Dim obj As New VisitorProfile

    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    con.Open()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    Try

        If txtName.Text.Trim().ToString() = "" Then
            lblError2.Text = ""
            lblError1.Text = "pls write name"
        ElseIf txtPassword.Text.Trim().ToString() = "" Then
            lblError1.Text = ""
            lblError2.Text = "pls write password"
            'ElseIf Not dr.HasRows = txtName.Text.Trim() Then
            '    lblError1.Text = "your Account is incorrect"
            ' ElseIf Not dr.HasRows = txtPassword.Text.Trim() Then
            '      lblError2.Text = "your Password is incorrect"
        ElseIf Not ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() Then

            MsgBox("Sorry Please try again !", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid Login")

        ElseIf Not dr.HasRows Then

            MsgBox("Sorry Please try again !", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid Login")

        ElseIf dr.Read Then

            txtName.Text = dr("AccountName").ToString()
            txtPassword.Text = dr("Password").ToString()
            obj.StringPass = txtName.Text
            MsgBox("welcome")
            obj.Show()
            VisitorProfile.lblwelcome.Text = txtName.Text
            Me.Hide()

        Else
            con.Close()
            MsgBox("Sorry Please try again", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "invalid login")


        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try



End Sub
```

Comment: Well, what's the `String` value being converted to a `Long`?  Is it a valid number?  It would appear not.  Did you bother to look?

Comment: Add `Option Strict On` to the top of your code file.  This line:  `ElseIf Not ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() Then` makes no sense as `If` requires a `Boolean`.  Which line in your code throws the exception?

Comment: conversion from string "Visitor" to type 'Long' is not valid

Comment: this is an error message from my codes

Comment: erm... i found the solution that ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()  changing to ComboBox1.text and then it is working now.   haha